# Python/Pandas: updating a XML-file from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I'm trying to update a xml-file with data from a pandas DataFrame:
The xml-file looks like this:

```
<root>
    <NetworkData>
        <Element loadid="23" type="Load" node1="N23">
            <Name>load1</Name>
            <ShortName/>
            <InputState>1027</InputState>
            <x>11</x>
            <y>15</y>
        </Element>
        <Element loadid="24" type="Load" node1="N24">
            <Name>load2</Name>
            <ShortName/>
            <InputState>1027</InputState>
            <x>0.75</x>
            <y>600</y>
        </Element>
        ...
```

The DataFrame looks like:

| ID | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 17 | 29 |
| 24 | 123 | 543 |
| ... | ... | ... |

The `ID` is identical to the `loadid` in the xml-file. My aim is to update the values `x` and `y` in the xml-file with the values from the Dataframe. Is there a easy way do to this because the Dataframe is quite long? By the way all `loadids` can be found as `IDs` in the Dataframe.
Output xml-file:

```
  <root>
    <NetworkData>
        <Element loadid="23" type="Load" node1="N23">
            <Name>load1</Name>
            <ShortName/>
            <InputState>1027</InputState>
            <x>17</x>
            <y>29</y>
        </Element>
        <Element loadid="24" type="Load" node1="N24">
            <Name>load2</Name>
            <ShortName/>
            <InputState>1027</InputState>
            <x>123</x>
            <y>543</y>
        </Element>
        ...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree

# create test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [23,24,25,26,27],
    'x': [21,22,23,24,25],
    'y': [101,102,103,104,105]
})

# create xml as a string (in your code it could be a file)
text = '''<root>
    <NetworkData>
        <Element loadid="23" type="Load" node1="N23">
            <Name>load1</Name>
            <ShortName/>
            <InputState>1027</InputState>
            <x>11</x>
            <y>15</y>
        </Element>
        <Element loadid="24" type="Load" node1="N24">
            <Name>load2</Name>
            <ShortName/>
            <InputState>1027</InputState>
            <x>0.75</x>
            <y>600</y>
        </Element>
        <Element loadid="99" type="Load" node1="N24">
            <Name>load2</Name>
            <ShortName/>
            <InputState>1027</InputState>
            <x>0.75</x>
            <y>600</y>
        </Element>
    </NetworkData>
  </root>
'''

# convert string to xml 
# (in your code it could be read from file instead)
doc = etree.fromstring(text)

# iterate over elements "Element"
for el in doc.xpath(".//NetworkData/Element"):
  # retrieve id from attribute value
  id = el.get('loadid')
  # retrieve appropriate row from dataframe
  row = df[df['ID'] == int(id)]
  # if found, update x and y
  if len(row) == 1:
      # find "x" element
      x = el.find('./x')
      # if found, update
      if x is not None:
        x.text = str(row['x'].item())
      # find "y" element
      y = el.find('./y')
      # if found update
      if y is not None:
        y.text = str(row['y'].item())
  # if there was no match found, update x and y with "0" values
  elif len(row) == 0:
      # find "x" element
      x = el.find('./x')
      # if found, update
      if x is not None:
        x.text = '0'
      # find "y" element
      y = el.find('./y')
      # if found update
      if y is not None:
        y.text = '0'

# save changed XML
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you! This works fine. I have another question: There are several x and y entries in the xml- file which have no corresponding ID in the DataFrame (row = df[df['ID'] == int(id)] is not fulfilled). In this case I would like to set x and y to zero in the xml-file. Have you an idea how i could modify your solution above?

Comment: Sure. Update answer with the `elif` branch which updates `x` and `y` with default zero values.

Comment: Thank you! You have helped me a lot, I'm a absolute beginner.